# How to completely disable Calendar network access in macOS (High Sierra)

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I would like the Calendar app in High Sierra to **not** check my location for timing conflicts, make location (or any other) suggestions, confer with Siri, and otherwise look for ways for Apple to link my calendar to the cloud.

Can the Calendar app's functionality be limited to non-networked behavior only?

Is there some Calendar agent I can permanently disable to accomplish this?

Comment: If your issue is about timing, you can [turn on time zone support](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/use-different-time-zones-icl1035/mac)

Comment: My issue has nothing to do with timing.

Comment: `CalendarAgent` is the most evil process I've ever met. It syncs continuosly (even when unneded; even when telling to sync manually). It hogs CPU at every network interaction (going to toilet and coming back in 5mins? CalendarAgent will try to re-syncronise).... – In my experience is monolitic, cannot be configured, cannot be controlled, cannot be limited (and if you try to limit its CPU, the Calendar UI will freeze at every single click), cannot be removed, and it's tightly bound with the system. .... is a serious piece of crap.